# How to create the custom drop down list in android

Tags: android

Hello I am new in the android and need to create the custom drop down list in android.

I searched on stackoverflow and google but did not find way to create custom drop down list.

Please help me to create it

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/biQjK.png

Please check the above link

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom `ListView` and LsitView's rows and then use `ViewGroup`:

```
ViewGroup dropDownMenu = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.dropDownMenuList);
dropDownMenu.setVisibility(dropDownMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Another alternative is to customize `ExpandableListView`: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html or `Spinner`.